# Disabling a checkbox by getting its name from a server

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, server

It is quite a bit hard to explain what I have in mind but I will try my best...

I have an installer with a ton of checkboxes. Each checkbox is mod (modification for a game). At times mods interfere with a game and cause the game to crash. So I have to update the installer with either updated mod(s) or I have to temporarily disable the mod or mods that are causing the crashing.

What it will do is connect to a server that checks if a file contains "true or false" if it contains "true" it will execute code that does this:

Connects to a different server, gets the name of a checkbox, and does something like this:

NameOfCheckBox.Enabled = False

The thing is... I know how to do this, except the very last part.

How do I tell my program that the text it gets from the server is a name of checkbox that is located on the form?

This is my code:

```
Try

        Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G3R0CoRG-LCXy-8jm-LcCJZJ9B0whsOJ64efjL0btc8/edit?usp=sharing")
        Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim status As String = sr.ReadToEnd()

        Dim request2 As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cYkhGTDEpxqltOvCSSD0Kw9J_1DG1dyJSV2qQ1Xekto/edit?usp=sharing")
        Dim response2 As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request2.GetResponse()
        Dim sr2 As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream())
        Dim checkboxtodisable As String = sr2.ReadToEnd()


        If status.Contains("True") Then
            Dim chk As CheckBox
            chk.Name = checkboxtodisable
            chk.Enabled = False
        Else

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to server!")
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

The error I get is:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

The error is located on this line of code:

```
chk.Name = checkboxtodisable
```

Comment: Try creating a new `CheckBox`... For example: `Dim chk As New CheckBox` if that doesn't work make sure `checkboxtodisable` is not nothing...

Comment: I don't get any errors... But the checkbox does not become disabled.

Comment: Of course, but that is your problem (your error). I knew it wouldn't change the state, but that isn't the error. If you want to include that, then update your post with relevant information.

Comment: @436f6465786572 I apologize for possible a stupid question.. But what do you mean it is my error? What I want to do is either uncheck or disable a checkbox remotely by placing the checkboxes name on a server.

Comment: I am referring to the error you posted above in your question. I was saying that's your first problem, your next problem would be getting the control you want to toggle is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a control by name like this:

```
Dim MyCheckBox As Checkbox = Me.Controls("checkbox1")
```

So your code would look like this:

```
If status.Contains("True") Then
    Dim chk as checkbox = Me.Controls(checkboxtodisable)
    chk.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: Is that case sensitive?

Comment: No.  And I'm not sure exactly what you're expecting `chk.Enabled = False` to do, but make sure you're not confusing that with `chk.Checked = False`

Comment: No I am not confusing .Enabled and .Checked... However if I would be able to uncheck the checkbox through the server that would suit me as well.

Comment: About your code... Unfortunately, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Remove the quotes around checkboxtodisable---I will edit answer.

Comment: I already tried removing the quotes and playing around with your code... It doesn't work :( thank you VERY much for trying to help me though :)

Comment: Are you sure that the string `checkboxtodisable` has the name, and only the name, of the control?  If there is a carriage return or line feed in it it won't work.  Try `Me.Controls(checkboxtodisable.Trim)`.

Comment: @TonyHinkle I think the problem with your code is lack of error checking.  Adding an If chk IsNot Nothing Then before chk.Enabled = False would avoid the exception.  Although, it raise the question of why the control is not found.